# Create path recursively in c in windows OS

Tags: c++, winapi

I have to create a directory structure recursively in C

Currently I am using the following logic in c++:

```
void createDirectoryRecursively(std::wstring path)
{
  unsigned int pos = 0;
  do
  {
    pos = path.find_first_of(L"\\/", pos + 1);
    CreateDirectory(path.substr(0, pos).c_str(), NULL);
  } while (pos != std::string::npos);
}
```

How can I create a directory structure recursively in a single API functions call in windows by providing only the path I need?

Comment: you can use [`SHCreateDirectoryEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762131(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: First sentence of the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762131.aspx) you linked to: *"This function is available through Windows XP Service Pack 2 (SP2) and Windows Server 2003. It might be altered or unavailable in subsequent versions of Windows."*

Comment: Create the directories one level at a time